# When do I create a service class

Tags: c#, architecture

When do I create a business service aka ConfigurationService.

When the logic in the service has access to a database or filesystem?

When is a class a service?

Is reading an xml file a ConfigurationReader and not ConfigurationService because it has no database access?

Comment: This question very much depends how you define _service_.

Comment: @Gusdor but this is my problem. Service is something abstract, but doing business logic. But an entity could do that too. On the other side an entity is an object in the real world (but thats not always true) a service has nothing to do with object in the real world (hm... I just realize thats also not true). Then some say an entity is database agnostic what is good and a service is sometimes not database agnostic. I could go on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally *I* distinguish services from domain objects by the fact that they are stateless.  They often (but not always) have access to sources of state (like databases or file systems), but they do not contain it themselves.

So, if ConfigurationReader reads the configuration from the passed xml, and then keeps that configuration in local variables, it's a domain object.  If it reads the configuration, and returns the "parsed" configuration objects, then it's a service.

Like the above comment though, this is all semantics, and other people's definition will vary greatly.

Comment: In my understanding a service is not always stateless because they are caching data which I do not want to get costly from the dataprovider again and again. "... will vary greatly..." that means there can not be an answer? :/

Comment: Caching is a very different concern from state-storage.  And has very different scaling concerns.  In caching, data can be not present, and still have the operation succeed (albeit more slowly), whereas state storage requires that the service have the data in order to succeed.

Comment: I do not consider services that cache as "stateful".  Also, I try to keep my caching behind a DAO layer, not in a services layer.  This makes caching more invisible to the service layer, and puts the data access in the "correct" place from a design standpoint.